# Convert a ListenableFuture chain to the equivalent RxJava structure

Tags: java, rx-java, guava, future, rx-java2

Using Guava [Listenable Futures](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained)

Assume I have the following class:

```
public class FooService {
    ListenableFuture<Foo> getFoo() {
        //code to create callable, then
        return listeningExecutorService.submit(fooCallable);
    }
}
```

and the following class:

```
public class BarService {
    ListenableFuture<Bar> getBar(Foo foo) {
        //code to create callable, then
        return listeningExecutorService.submit(barCallable);
    }
}
```

Note that `getBar` requires a `Foo` in the parameters.

If I want to chain these two operations together I would write a transformer function like this:

```
AsyncFunction<Foo, Bar> fooToBar = new AsyncFunction<Foo, Bar>() {

     @Override
     ListenableFuture<Bar> apply(Foo resultantFoo) {
         return barService.get(resultantFoo);
     }
};
```

and then apply the transformation like this:

```
public ListenableFuture<Bar> combinedFooToBar() {
     ListenableFuture<Foo> futureFoo = fooService.get();
     return Futures.transformAsync(futureFoo, fooToBar);
}
```

**Question**: what is the equivalent syntax for these classes and transformation function if we were to convert them into RxJava? Assume that we want to convert `FooService` and `BarService` into the appropriate RxJava structures. Assume we want to chain async tasks using the result of calling `FooService` as the parameter for `BarService`.

NB: I am just starting to learn about RxJava syntax. When I have finished studying the syntax I will attempt answer the question myself. However, in the meantime if anyone wants to answer they are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Guava code translates into RxJava2 code as follows:

**FooService.java**

```
public class FooService {

    Observable<Foo> getFoo() {
        return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Foo>() {
            @Override
            public Foo call() throws Exception {
                return new Foo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**BarService.java**

```
public class BarService {

    Observable<Bar> getBar(final Foo foo) {
        return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Bar>() {
            @Override
            public Bar call() throws Exception {
                return new Bar(foo);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**FooBarService.java**

```
public class FooBarService {

    private final FooService fooService;
    private final BarService barService;

    public FooBarService(FooService fooService, BarService barService) {
        this.fooService = fooService;
        this.barService = barService;
    }

    Observable<Bar> getFooBar() {
        return fooService.getFoo()
                .concatMap(new Function<Foo, ObservableSource<? extends Bar>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ObservableSource<? extends Bar> apply(@NonNull Foo foo) throws Exception {
                        return barService.getBar(foo);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Hence, [`concatMap`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#concatMap(io.reactivex.functions.Function)) and [`flatMap`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#flatMap(io.reactivex.functions.Function)) are similar to `Futures.transformAsync` and [`map`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#map(io.reactivex.functions.Function)) is similar to `Futures.transform` (non-async).

Note also this Github project called [Future Converter](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/future-converter) for conversion between `ListenableFuture` and `Observable`.